# How can I get rid of the bacteremia in the floating in the air!

Tags: air-quality

How can I get rid of all that chemical bacteremia floating in the air!

Comment: Bacteremia is, by definition, the condition of having bacteria in your blood. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Chemicals and bacteria are different things.  Is this related to your other question about fiberglass?

Comment: are you a germophobe?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, antiseptics are off-topic here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about home improvement.

Answer (score 2):

You'll never be able to sterilize your air. Bacteria are everywhere. The ones in and on your body, combined, add up to about the weight of your brain<sup>[1](http://www.center4research.org/bacteria-good-bad-ugly/)</sup>.

If you're dealing with a specific short-term contamination, open windows. A few minutes of robust breeze would almost completely replace the air in a home, and eliminate nearly all of the bacteria in it. Of course, new bacteria arrive as well.

You could also use a HEPA-rated air filtration device. Many are designed to capture particles as small as a bacterium. This would be very slow by comparison to the window approach and wouldn't protect you for some time.